# XMLTextWriter To WiterData Using C#.Net Application

Tags: xml

We have thousand of Data To Write In XML File & To Write Data We use XmlTextWriter.

We can across one problem while Writing XML File,

**Error Is While Writing Attribute** : Invalid high surrogate character (0xDC50). A high surrogate character must have a value from range (0xD800 - 0xDBFF).

**As A Error Solution** : We decided to Replace Problematic Data With Space..

But XMLTextWriter Wan't Allow To Write Anything After WriterState is In Error.
(**it Says : Token StartAttribute in state Error would result in an invalid XML document**.)

Here is sample Code To Relicate Error:

XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter("C:\employees.xml", Encoding.UTF8);
  writer.WriteStartDocument();
  writer.WriteStartElement("Employees");

```
           try
            {
                string data = "뿿�� ";
                writer.WriteAttributeString("Company", data);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
              //Here I Got Error For surrogate character                     
                writer.WriteAttributeString("Company", "");//Trying To Write Again   
            }
```

Is there any way To write Attribute value ones it get in State Of Error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check your data string before adding it to the writer or use a CDATA block using : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextwriter.writecdata.aspx

Comment: Thanks For Your Reply..I tried using CDATA Block By  writer.WriteCData(data); stil it throws same error..